# How to summarize values when column values are identical?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am pretty much using Tableau as a pivot table here. How can I summarize the order volume column so that, because all of the previous column values are the same, it will read as 3 instead of 1 and 2? Sum() hasn't worked for me.

Thank you!!!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IAOk.png)

Comment: did the answer solved your needs? if so, please accept the answer in order to mark the thread as closed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided as sample, you may want to calculate the max value for that specific column, in order to have just one "aggregated value".

Using the superstore dataset you can replicate this, trying to calculate the max Order ID for a specific customer regardless the number of rows:

```
{ FIXED [Customer Name] : max ([Order ID])}
```

The result could look like this:

[image]